# Where does OS X save environment variables?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting JAVA_HOME environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/240100/setting-java-home-environment-variable)

When you type "echo $JAVA_HOME" in Mac, where does Mac look to find the value of JAVA_HOME?
In other words where does Mac save environment variables?

Comment: Your question asks "where does OS X _save_ environment variables?"  Although the answers have discussed how to _set_ variables, is this really what you're asking?

If so, then the answer is "in the environment"!  Each process (ie each application, and each command run from the command line) has an environment which stores, amongst other things, the set of variables.

When you create a _new_ process (for example you create a new terminal window, or run a new program) the new process gets a copy of the environment of the current process, including any variables you've set in that process.  W

Answer (score 1):

In your home directory's .profile file. (ex: /Users/Mahdi/.profile)

Answer (score 1):

A similar question/answer was posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x). The solution describes that you should create a ~/.profile and define the environment variables at this level. You can check out the [Apple Reference Library on setting environment variables](http://snipurl.com/apple_environment) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables may be defined in all the usual places for a bash shell session. There is also an optional special file $HOME/.MacOSX/environment.plist which can contain environment variables for apps etc.

Answer (score 0):

Put this: `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home` (or location of your Java lib) in `~/.bash_profile`