# Setting JAVA_HOME environment variable

Tags: macos, java, environment-variables

I have set java_home on my mac, by putting `export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks/Home` to my `~/.profile file`. I quit the terminal and ran it again.

But when I typed `echo $JAVA_HOME` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> it shows `JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks/Version/1.6.0_22/Home` which is not the right one. How can I fix this problem & change this ?

Comment: What Mac OS X version are you using? Try navigating to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks/` and open `Home` to see if it's an alias. Command-click the folder name in the title bar to see the full path. If it's `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks/Version/1.6.0_22/Home`, the alias was simply resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Since 10.6 (I think -- may be earlier), the recommended way of setting the JAVA_HOME variable is using `/usr/libexec/java_home`, via something like

```
% export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

There are various options you can add to the command to select a suitable JAVA_HOME given various constraints.  See the java_home manpage for details.

The general idea is that the structure under `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks` isn't documented and may in principle change from release to release.